# Is it plausible that Earth's magnetism can induce heart attacks by affecting red blood cells?

Tags: electromagnetism, estimation, biology, geomagnetism

[https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014cosp...40E1114G/abstract#%3A~%3Atext%3DIt%20was%20shown%20statistically%20that%2Ccomparison%20with%20quiet%20geomagnetic%20conditions](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014cosp...40E1114G/abstract#%3A%7E%3Atext%3DIt%20was%20shown%20statistically%20that%2Ccomparison%20with%20quiet%20geomagnetic%20conditions)

This study says that on average, rates of heart attack and brain stroke increased by an average factor of two(!) during geomagnetic disturbances. Geomagnetic disturbances are merely fluctuations in Earth's magnetic field, or geomagnetism. These fluctuations are caused by solar storms. The study is suggesting that Earth's geomagnetism is causing heart problems.

> It was shown statistically that **during geomagnetic disturbances the frequency of myocardial infarction and brain stroke cases increased on the average by a factor of two in comparison with quiet geomagnetic conditions**.

They offer this mechanism for this observation:

> Our investigations show the red blood cells are very sensitive to electromagnetic forces. Most probable that geomagnetic fluctuations (frequency) acting on blood, brain, adrenals involves the adaptation system. This leads to increasing a level of catecholamines in blood responsible for activation of the clotting system, rise in aggregation and spasm in the afferent vessels of the microcirculatory network. In persons suffering from CHD, the foreground problem is the reversibility of these pathological processes.

On the other hand, USGS, a government domain website, asserts that Earth's magnetism does not affect health:

https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/does-earths-magnetic-field-affect-human-health

> "Does the Earth's magnetic field affect human health? The Earth's
> magnetic field does not directly affect human health. Humans evolved
> to live on this planet.
>
> High altitude pilots and astronauts can experience higher levels of
> radiation during magnetic storms, but the hazard is due to the
> radiation, not the magnetic field itself. **Geomagnetism can also impact
> the electrically based technology that we rely on, but it does not
> impact people themselves.**
>
> Learn more: USGS Geomagnetism Program"

Is it plausible that Earth's geomagnetism causes the rate of heart attacks to double? Is the mechanism suggested by [https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014cosp...40E1114G/abstract#%3A~%3Atext%3DIt%20was%20shown%20statistically%20that%2Ccomparison%20with%20quiet%20geomagnetic%20conditions](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014cosp...40E1114G/abstract#%3A%7E%3Atext%3DIt%20was%20shown%20statistically%20that%2Ccomparison%20with%20quiet%20geomagnetic%20conditions) in any way plausible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question describes  is an application of physics and belongs  to https://biology.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

> Is it plausible that Earth's geomagnetism causes the rate of heart attacks to double?

No, it is not even remotely plausible.

First, a doubling in the rate of heart attacks is huge. You would expect to see a large number of papers on the topic in the standard peer reviewed journals like Lancet, Circulation, and New England Journal of Medicine. It would not be only reported in a likely non-peer-reviewed abstract to a single conference.

Second, almost all biological effects show a dose dependent effect. If a geomagnetic storm is a sufficient dose of EM exposure to double the risk of a heart attack, then entering a MRI room would be expected to cause heart attacks at an even higher rate. Since this is not observed, then whatever effect is being seen in the data is not plausibly linked to magnetic exposure.

Third, if you look at the publication history of that particular author, you will find that they primarily publish in predatory journals. Meaning that their papers almost exclusively come from journals that will publish anything regardless of how bad it is as long as the author pays the fee. Such journals are money-making scams, not scientific outlets.

This simply is not plausible. A related discussion can be found here:

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/do-fluctuations-in-earths-magnetic-field-cause-heart-attacks.1058145

Comment: Is NewScientist also a predatory journal? https://www.newscientist.com/article/2324402-solar-storms-may-cause-up-to-5500-heart-related-deaths-in-a-given-year/

Comment: @Malcom NewScientist is not a scientific journal at all. It is a news magazine

Comment: I heard that this study is peer reviewed/in a reputable journal. https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4433/12/3/306

Comment: @Malcom MDPI is a predatory publisher, in my opinion. I wouldn’t accept anything found only in MDPI, Hindawi, Frontiers, vixra, or ResearchGate.

Comment: It’s sad, but I have to agree with Dale. I am regularly offered 24hr turnaround times if I publish in MDPI journals, which is obviously not possible with anything resembling peer review. Suffice to say I do not accept such offers.

Comment: Reading the article, I think they may have hunted until they found a correlation.  They split up their samples into small sizes (age, sex, season) and then looked at a whole bunch of possible metrics.  Now I'll readily admit that I'm not the best reader of these papers, but for their largest correlation, HSSW, it looked to me like they intentionally drew the cutoff wherever it would have the most correlation.

Comment: I looked briefly at this topic and it seems it's more reputable than it might appear at first glance. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00484-022-02382-3, https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/JAHA.120.021006 and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1052305717304883 are examples. However, all the examples I saw were correlational studies. It's hard to imagine a causative link.

Comment: https://www.health.com/condition/stroke/solar-flare-health-effects is another source. To quote, "The change in the magnetic field we're talking about is really small. If you think of the magnetic field that causes your compass needle to point north, we're talking about a 10th of a percent of that fluctuation". Plus since the solar cycle has been around forever, one would expect living beings to have evolved to minimize its effect.  It's hard to imagine a causative link. Not to say it's *impossible*, though.

Comment: @Allure none of those references support the specific claim “that Earth's geomagnetism causes the rate of heart attacks to double”. That is the specific claim in the question, which is not at all credible.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to say no that it is not plausible or likely simply because every single cell in the human body has a cellular wall around it that acts as an insulator for the cell itself and even though a fluid that acts as an insulator can indeed be charged, the charge is immediately dispersed to the outer edge of the insulating fluid in a 360° range which leaves the center of the cell in a untouched neutral state. So even with a magnetism type charge, the center of the cell (nucleus) would be undisturbed allowing it to function at a normal capacity. This holds true for every single cell that is found in the human body. (Not including dry exodermal skin cells.)
Physics ≥ Statistics. 8)

Comment: What are your thoughts on this study, which says that Earth's geomagnetism causes heart problems? https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014cosp...40E1114G/abstract#%3A%7E%3Atext%3DIt%20was%20shown%20statistically%20that%2Ccomparison%20with%20quiet%20geomagnetic%20conditions